# Replace a value in df based on another df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, conditional-formatting

I'm using R. I have 2 dataframes:

```
column_a <- c("20", "30", "40", "60")
column_b <- c("1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5")
column_c <- c("30", "50", "60", "70")
column_d <- c("2.3", "4.5", "6.7", "8.9")

df1 <- data.frame(column_a, column_b)
df2 <- data.frame (column_c, column_d)
```

What I need to do is this: if a value in column_a is present in column_c, the corresponding value in column_b must replace the value in column_d.

The new df2 should look like this:

```
  column_c column_d
1       30      1.3
2       50      4.5
3       60      1.5
4       70      8.9
```

As you can see, the values "2.3" and "6.7" have been replaced by "1.3" and "1.5", respectively, as "30" and "60" are the only values that are present both in the column_c of df_2 and in column_a of df_1.

Comment: Please double-check your expected result table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may join the dataframe and replace the values with `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c('column_c' = 'column_a')) %>%
  transmute(column_c, column_d = coalesce(column_b, column_d))

#  column_c column_d
#1       30      1.3
#2       50      4.5
#3       60      1.5
#4       70      8.9
```

In base R -

```
transform(merge(df2, df1, all.x = TRUE, by.x = 'column_c', by.y = 'column_a'), 
          column_d = ifelse(is.na(column_b), column_d, column_b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

column_a <- c("20", "30", "40", "60")
column_b <- c("1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5")
column_c <- c("30", "50", "60", "70")
column_d <- c("2.3", "4.5", "6.7", "8.9")

df1 <- data.frame(column_a, column_b)
df2 <- data.frame(column_c, column_d)

df1
#>   column_a column_b
#> 1       20      1.2
#> 2       30      1.3
#> 3       40      1.4
#> 4       60      1.5
df2
#>   column_c column_d
#> 1       30      2.3
#> 2       50      4.5
#> 3       60      6.7
#> 4       70      8.9

bind_cols(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(
    column_b = ifelse(column_a == column_c, column_d, column_b)
  ) %>%
  select(column_c, column_d)
#>   column_c column_d
#> 1       30      2.3
#> 2       50      4.5
#> 3       60      6.7
#> 4       70      8.9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With basic R `ifelse` command:

```
df2$column_d = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {ifelse(x['column_c'] %in% df1$column_a,
               df1[df1$column_a == x['column_c'], 'column_b'], x['column_d'])})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, column_d := fcoalesce(column_b, column_d), on = .(column_c = column_a)]
> df2
   column_c column_d
1:       30      1.3
2:       50      4.5
3:       60      1.5
4:       70      8.9
```